# Bootstrap tabs in Chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have some Bootstrap tabs in my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 400px;
        width: 288px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>

<html lang="en">

<div class="container" id="mainPopup">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">C</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="A">Content inside tab A</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="B">Content inside tab B</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="C">Content inside tab C</div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Here is the HTML being displayed in a webpage and in a Chrome extension:

[image]

The code in the browser allows me to change tabs, but the one in the Chrome browser extension one doesn't. What is the reason to this, and how can I get Bootstrap to work in the Chrome extension?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out you can't link external Javascript files at the top of your HTML file. I had to download the Bootstrap files and save them locally in order for them to be used in an extension.

Answer (score 8):

We can use external JavaScripts. [Read this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

In your `manifest.json` add `content_security_policy` key. i.e

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'self';"
```

I'm using jQuery as well as Bootstrap.

In your case add this line in your `manifest.json`

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'self';"
```